# Is Google indexing pages that has no connection with other pages?

Tags: search-engine-indexing, google-index, noindex

I am working on a web project that has nearly 100 thousand instant users and there is a webpage that we are using for test cases. There are no links pointing to it from other pages. It shouldn't be indexed by Google or any other search engines.

"[noindex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noindex)" can be used in this situation, I know but I wonder if Google (or any others) indexes this page, if I don't do anything to prevent it.

Answer (score 2):

Googlebot (the web crawler of Google) can discover your page by different ways:

- if it finds a link to your page from a web page (inside or outside your domain name)
- if you submit the URL to your Google Webmaster Tools account through a *sitemap.xml*

In that case, the page can be indexed. In most of cases, Googlebot decides to index it (for example, it's not the case when your page has a lot of duplicate content with another page).

If you don't want this page indexed, just put this `<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">` tag in your page and block the page with your *robots.txt* like this:

```
User-agent: Googlebot (or * for all web crawlers)
Disallow: /the-page
```

Answer (score 1):

If web crawlers get to this page one way or another, and if it is not marked as `noindex` and it is not blocked in your *robots.txt*, then yes, they may decide to index it.

You may also use `noarchive` to make sure they don't keep a cached version of it.

Answer (score 0):

No, Google doesn't automatically index your pages, if no other site links to them. You should put a *robots.txt* file on the root directory of your server, which can prevent the search engine from indexing the pages of a specific folder.

It could look like this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Comment: It's better to use the NOINDEX robots tag on the pages because it might index pages even if it's not "allowed to crawl".

Comment: @Christoph Bühler: Allan S. Hansen is right and no, if a page has no connection, Google can't find it.

Comment: Google can find pages without inbound links when they are in accessible sitemaps.

Comment: @JVerstry: This is what I said in my answer :-).

Comment: Sorry... too much coffee I guess... lol